# Curl of vector product with constant and position vector in index notation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, index-notation

I need to show that for a given constant vector **C** and position vector **R**

Curl [ (**C** × **R**) ×**R** ] = **3C** × **R**

I treat **R** as  x<sub>i</sub>e<sub>i</sub>. This is what I've tried so far but the second position vector **R** is throwing me off:

\begin{align*}
   \nabla \times ((\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{R}) \times \mathbf{R})
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i ((\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{R}) \times \mathbf{R})_j \mathbf{e}_k \\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i (\epsilon_{\ell mj} (\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{R})_\ell x_m)\mathbf{e}_k \\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_i (\epsilon_{\ell mj} \epsilon_{rp\ell}x_r c_p  x_m) \mathbf{e}_k\\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{\ell mj} \epsilon_{rp\ell} \partial_i x_r x_m  c_p \mathbf{e}_k\\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{\ell mj} \epsilon_{rp\ell} \delta_{ir} c_p  x_m \mathbf{e}_k\\
   &= \epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{\ell mj} \epsilon_{ip\ell} c_p  x_m \mathbf{e}_k\\
\end{align*}
I think I'm going wrong on the delta line where I make kronecker delta ir, but the x<sub>m</sub> is still there. After this I tried using the contraction identity on the first and last symbol because they both start with i
$$
    \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ip\ell} = \delta_{jp}\delta_{k\ell} - \delta_{j\ell}\delta_{kp}
$$
This leads onto:
\begin{align*}
    \epsilon_{\ell mj}\delta_{jp}\delta_{k\ell} &= \epsilon_{kmp} \\
    \epsilon_{\ell mj}\delta_{j\ell}\delta_{kp} &= \epsilon_{\ell m\ell} = 0
\end{align*}

Which doesn't help me solve the equation so I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Using direct definition, anyway it works :

Let $C=(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ and $R=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.
Then $C\times R=(c_2x_3-c_3x_2,c_3x_1-c_1x_3,c_1x_2-c_2x_1)$
$$(C\times R)\times R=(*,(c_1x_2-c_2x_1)x_3-(c_2x_3-c_3x_2)x_3,(c_2x_3-c_3x_2)x_2-(c_3x_1-c_1x_3)x_1)$$

Then $[\nabla((C\times R)\times R)]_1=-c_3x_2+(c_2x_3-c_3x_2)-[-c_2x_3-(c_2x_3-c_3x_2)]=3(c_2x_3-c_3x_2)=3[C\times R]_1$

Hope this helps a bit.